# Auto scaling won't turn off no matter what I do

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using visual studio to make an app, but for some reason, the form always scales, no matter what. I keep setting it to (800, 500), but in the designer, it always appears as (778, 444). I've turned off auto scale mode, and I've tried deleting the code for auto scaling, but for some reason it keeps changing its size. Does anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Are you referring to the Form's `Size` or the `ClientSize`? When you set the Size in the PropertyGrid, you actually set the `ClientSize`.

Comment: this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(778, 444);

I keep setting the size for form1 as (800, 500) on the form1 design, but it always sets the actual size to (778, 444) on the designer. If I edit the code on the designer, the size on the design is then too big, and the program acts as if it is that size.

Comment: That is correct. As mentioned, when you set the Form's Size in the PropertyGrid, it will set the `ClientSize` in Designer.cs (the `ClientSize` doesn't include the non-client area, usually, the Borders and Caption). This because when you set the `ClientSize`, the Windows size is adjusted for Dpi (`AdjustWindowRectExForDpi()`) if your app receives DPi change notifications, or to a standard Size based on System settings (`AdjustWindowRectEx()`). -- It's not clear what Size you want your Form to be set to. - VS issues a warning when you don't design at 100% scale, you shouldn't ignore it